# How to programatically unload a view controller from Tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tab bar controller in storyboard, with 5 tab bar items. I want to remove one view controller programatically from the "viewcontrollers" array of the tab bar stack. I also want the app to be show some other tab item as selected when i remove the above view controller. I have tried with the below code, but its not working.

```
if let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at: 2)
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: have you tried asigning a new array of viewControllers that lacks the one you want to remove?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ No, i just removed the view controller from the array. Will try that.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Its not working, even though the view controller is getting removed.

Comment: try out my updated answer

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Tried that now..still not working..has it got something to do with the creation of tab bar in storyboard ?

Comment: what do you mean by it did not work? what happened?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ The tab bar is not switching to the selected index (ie: 1) instead it remains in the same tab that i was trying to remove. But in the console when i log and see i can see that the view controller is not listed in the "viewcontrollers" array.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now.. where is this code called from? Which view controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161091/discussion-between-subin272-and-milan-nosa).

Comment: @MilanNosáľ 
This code is getting called from the same view controller via a delegate method. I am actually loading a camera view from the tab item (presenting modally) and on dismissing that view the delegate method in the view controller is getting called. That is where i have written the remove method.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Yes it worked now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassign `viewControllers` property without the one you don't want:

```
if let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
    var controllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
    controllers.remove(at: 2)
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
}
```

Now this code is ok, but the problem is the following line:

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController
```

This creates a new `UITabBarController` instance - but you want to access the one that was instantiated by the storyboads and that is presented on the screen. However, without more context it's hard to give you suggestions on how to access it. Considering that you call this code from a viewController directly embedded in the tab bar controller, I would start with this:

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
    var controllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
    controllers.remove(at: 2)
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the "instantiateViewController" line. This method actually creates a new instance of the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    if let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController {
        var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
        viewControllers.remove(at: 2)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

Comment: I can see that the view controller is getting removed from the "viewControllers" array when i check in debugger. But the application is still displaying the view controller and the "viewDidLoad" is not getting called again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {

    let indexToRemove = 3

    if indexToRemove < tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {

        var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers

        viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)

        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that the view controller is getting removed from the "viewControllers" array when i check in debugger. But the application is still displaying the view controller and the "viewDidLoad" is not getting called again.